# Pass multiple arguments to listbox

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, listbox

I am trying to pass a label to the callback function of my listbox, but somehow I can't manage to do it.

I already tried with lambdas, but without success.

This is my current code-snippet:

```
program_list.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', MainController.select_program)
```

How can I get something like:

```
program_list.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', MainController.select_program(arg1))
```

EDIT:
other function:

```
def select_program(selection, test):
global programs
print test
if not programs:
    return
# Tkinter passes an event object to onselect()
w = selection.widget
index = int(w.curselection()[0])
value = w.get(index)
print 'You selected item %d: "%s"' % (index, value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lambda like this:

**CHANGED**

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def on_select(event, arg):
    lb = event.widget
    idx = lb.curselection()
    item = lb.get(idx)
    print('%s, %s' % (item, arg))

lst = Listbox(root)
for i in range(5):
    lst.insert(END, 'item ' + str(i))
lst.pack()
lst.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', lambda event: on_select(event, 'another value'))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: But how can I keep the selection if I do it with lambda like you did in your first snipped? I edited the controller function in my main post

Comment: @QDA, I revised my answer. See the example.